# Max operating temperature for PCB/Chip antennas

Tags: antenna, temperature, wifi, pcb-antenna, patch-antenna

I'm looking for an antenna (PCB or chip), which I'd like to install in an environment that can exceed 110°C.

Here are my questions :

- Should I trust the temperature ranges given for antennas? The temperature ranges are actually present in the filters on websites (e.g. Mouser), but rarely in the datasheets.
- What impact temperature have on this type of component, since it's just a copper plate at the bottom? Is the impact is mainly on the (only) solder connecting the U. FI connector for PCB antennas?

Comment: You're probably OK, since what you're talking about is just copper (or some other conductor) and solder, both of which should be fine at 110C.  That being said, I'm not sure I would chose a part for that environment if the manufacturer doesn't state explicitly that the part is good at that temperature.